# Difference between instantiating then assigning vs declaring then assigning?

Tags: c#, .net, object, heap-memory, stack-memory

A friend of mine asked this to me. Although I answered it, I am not very convinced my self. All I seek is a satisfaction or a correction. The code snippet is below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Customer");
        dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        //and some more columns
        dt1.Rows.Add(1);

        *****//what is the difference between doing
        DataTable dt2 = dt1;
        //vs.
        DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
        dt3 = dt1;*****
    }
}
```

From what I know thus far, using a `new` keyword would create the object on the heap and a  pointer variable on the stack and stack is used only for simple data types like int, double, etc and pointers.

From my understanding, I explained that `dt2` would be created on the stack which is capable of pointing to any `DataTable` type in the heap, and as we assign `dt1` to `dt2`, it will point to the same data table `dt1`was pointing to. In the case of dt3, a new data table object is created on the heap and `dt3` will be pointing to it, but when we do `dt3 = dt1`, it starts pointing to `DataTable` pointed by `dt1` instead of the one created.

I am not very confident that I gave a proper explanation esp. the part about `dt3`. So I was hoping the community would either correct me or assure me I was right.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The second form is pointless.  You create a new `DataTable` but then immediately throw away the only reference you have to it by assigning `dt3` to `dt1` so the newly created `DataTable` just gets scheduled for garbage collection without having ever done anything.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you're right. In the line `DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();` you create a new `DataTable` object, with `dt3` reference pointing to it. Then, after `dt3 = dt1` you forget about this object. `dt3` is pointing to the previously created object, namely: `new DataTable("Customer")`. The object you "forgot" about will possibly be garbage collected, as there are no references to it.

Comment: Sweet! Basically then there is no point of doing the second approach. Ever! isn't it? Also, if such is the case I think I won't be wrong to say that 'new' keyword could be used literally to create new objects, if a variable is needed to point to existing object, it should be simply declared.

Comment: @HakuKalay Well I can imagine that in some very rare cases you might want to instantiate an object just for sake of calling its constructor, but in general, and in this particular example yes, there is no point in doing that.

Answer (score 3):

You're essentially correct.  Each of the variables `dt1`, `dt2`, and `dt3` are *references* to `DataTable` objects.  When the assignment operator is used between variables of class type, something called *assignment by reference* happens.  This means that when you type `dt3 = dt1`, you are changing `dt3` to refer to a completely different `DataTable` object - in this case, the same `DataTable` object that `dt1` is referring to.

It's important to note that this is part of the *reference semantics* of classes.  You correctly noted that "simple data types like int, double, etc" are allocated on the stack.  In fact, this is true of all structs.  In c#, the fundamental difference between classes and structs is that classes have *reference semantics*, and structs have *value semantics*.

This means that if instead of `class DataTable`, you had declared `struct DataTable`, then there would be three `DataTable` objects sitting on the stack, and the statement `dt3 = dt1` would copy the `DataTable` object in `dt1` *by value* into `dt3`.

Simple types like `int` and `bool` are actually structs, and thus live on the stack and are copied/passed by value.

Of course, any discussion about value types vs. reference types isn't complete without a link to Eric Lippert's article ["The Stack Is An Implementation Detail"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx).  I've talked a bit about structs "living on the stack" in this answer, but that was just to get the point across.  Try to get out of the habit of thinking of classes as "heap types" and structs as "stack types", and start thinking about them in terms of "reference types" and "value types".